# Pass Variable in URL Drupal 7

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am trying to pass variable in the url but without success.

In Drupal I have a page with:

```
require_once 'uploaded_files/individual_funds.php?id=8';
```

But I get an error: Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'uploaded_files/individual_funds.php?id=8

I understand that Drupal is looking specifically for this url and that why it's not working.  But I need to pass the variable into that page. 
Is there a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include only files. You can't call them via`require`, but you **can** do something like this:

```
$_GET['id'] = 8';
require_once 'uploaded_files/individual_funds.php';
```

This will set the get `id` parameter for the functions inside your required file.

Comment: How would i request that variable in the next .php?

Comment: I don't think you get the concept of the variables. You just the variable, you request it the same way.